# Reciprocation with respect to the unit circle

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Find the images of the circles $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$ and $(x-2)^2+y^2=9$ under reciprocation with respect to the unit circle.

This is my final exam question but I cannot do any thing about it. Please help me.

Comment: Is this a currently on-going exam, or was it the last problem on an exam that is finished, and you just want to know how to do it?

Comment: Reciprocation is a Moebius map: this sends circles into circles (where straight lines are considered circles of radius $\infty$). So, in particular, you should have been looking for some circles in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example any point $\;(a,b)\;$ in the first circle: $\;(a-2)^2+b^2=4\;$ . We want a point $\;(p,q)\;$ on the ray $\;(2,0)\to(a,b)\;$ , meaning: on the line

$$(2,0)+t(a,b)=(at+2,bt)\;,\;\;0\le t\in\Bbb R$$

s.t. $\;d((a,b),(2,0))\cdot d((p,q),(2,0))=1^2=1\;$ (with $\;d=\;$ distance) , and this means $\; d((p,q),(2,0))=\cfrac12\;$ .

Now, write $\;(p,q)=(at+2,bt)\;$ , for some $\;0\le t\in\Bbb R\;$ ,so we get

$$\frac14=d((p,q),(2,0))^2=a^2t^2+b^2t^2\implies t=\frac1{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

and your point is

$$\left(\,\frac a{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+2\,,\,\,\frac b{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\,\right)$$

Understand the above and fill in details, and do the other case.